# How to identify when a dwolla transaction has cleared?

Tags: dwolla

Right now I'm using a transaction status webhook to update my app when a payment changes status.  The other day, my web server was down when the webhook was triggered, so the status was never updated in my system, nor do I have any way to tell when the payment was marked "processed".

From the docs, when a webhook fails, it will immediately try the request another two times, but this is not helpful if my site is down for more than a few seconds.

I'd like to get the status on my own if possible, but there doesn't seem to be any info representing when the transaction was actually marked processed.

I'm guessing the "date" is the date the transaction was initiated and that "clearing date" is just an estimate of when it will be processed (and is not updated to reflect the actual date when the transaction is processed).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a payment's Transaction ID, you can look it up using the [Transactions/By ID](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/byid) method.

Which will give you this info about the payment:

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "Message": "Success",
    "Response": {
        "Amount": 1,
        "Date": "8/31/2011 10:19:09 AM",
        "DestinationId": "812-111-1111",
        "DestinationName": "Bob",
        "Id": 12345,
        "SourceId": "812-111-2222",
        "SourceName": "Alice",
        "Type": "money_sent",
        "UserType": "Dwolla",
        "Status": "processed",
        "ClearingDate": "",
        "Notes": "Thank you for lunch!",
        "Fees": [
            {
                "Id": 1646163,
                "Amount": 0.1,
                "Type": "Facilitator Fee"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The **Response.Status** field indicates a transaction's current status, which is what you're looking for.

Alternatively, you can use the [Transaction/Listing](https://developers.dwolla.com/dev/docs/transactions/listing) method to list all the recent (and older) transactions under your account, with the same data about them shown above.  You can filter the results and specify ranges by playing with the request parameters to narrow your search down and produce a list of transactions that occurred while your server was down.

You're right about the clearing date just being an estimate of when the payment will clear - it's not a guarantee.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  I am already using the transaction/id method to get what the current status is, but I'm still not sure how to tell WHEN the status was changed, as none of the dates presented by this API seem to represent when the record was last updated (or, more specifically, when it was marked 'processed').  The search method would be a clever solution, but there aren't any properties that would properly allow you to narrow it down between what records were updated when the server was down.